# How to add a tab (or other) UI component with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia, jquery-easyui, jqwidget

I'm trying to integrate some jQuery-based UI components into an Aurelia application (specifically, a tab component).  I have tried [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com) and [EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com) and have had the same problem with each.  They both work essentially the same way: you create some divs that represent your tabs, then call a method like `$('#divTabs').tabs()`.

I've created a custom element like this:

```
@customElement('tabs-element')
@inject(Element)
export class Tabs{
    @bindable items;
    @bindable areaId;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached(){
       $(this.element).tabs();
    }           
}
```

with a view like this:

```
<template>
    <div id.bind="areaId">
        <div repeat.for="item of items" title.bind="item.id">
            ${item.username}

            <!-- Eventually I want to use "compose" here  ->
            <!--<compose view-model="component/${item.name}"></compose>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I then use this element in my main view like this (where `users` is an array of objects fetched from the server):

```
<tabs-element area-id="TopArea" items.bind="users"></tabs-element>
```

This works fine when the page first loads, but when new data is subsequently fetched, I can't seem to recreate the tabs.  Aurelia's `repeat.for` updates the DOM with the new items, but I can't call `$('#divTabs').tabs()` again because the plugin already mucked with the divs (wrapped them in other divs, added classes, etc...) the first time around.
[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UjSJEr?p=preview) that shows the problem.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there a way to force my element to reload when the bound array changes?

Comment: you make the element as a class member right, so why can't you just call `$(this.element).tabs()` after you assign the new users to the class member users

Comment: Because the DOM structure at that point is already messed up from the first call to `$(this.element).tabs()`, and the plugin chokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted my question, I started reading about Aurelia's enhance capability, and I think that's the answer to my problem.  This lets me manage tab creation in code instead of markup (which I actually think is preferable anyway).

My custom element view is now basically empty (except for an empty div, which is required by the UI plugin).  I hook into the itemsChanged event and create the tabs there:

```
itemsChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    //semi-pseudo code here
    //clear out existing tabs
    $('#divTabs').tabs('clear');        

    //loop through item array and create a tab for each item    
    newValue.forEach(item => {
        $('#divTabs').tabs('addLast', item.ComponentTitle, '<div id="' + item.ComponentTitle + '"><compose view-model="component/' + item.ComponentName + '"></compose></div>');
        let el = document.querySelector('#' + item.ComponentTitle);
        this.templatingEngine.enhance({element: el});
    });
}
```

Upon further review, this seems to be similar to the way the [Kendo UI Bridge](http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/about/about) works, which makes me think that this is the right track.  Many thanks to [this post](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/01/enhancing-at-will-using-aurelias-templating-engine-enhance-api/) for shedding light on this feature.